# ChicagoBoss render specific fields

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I have this code:

```
get_users('GET', []) ->
    Users = boss_db:find(consumer, []),
    {json, [{users, Users}]}.
```

But my `users` contains for example `password` field which I don't want to render. How to exclude some fields from rendring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ChicagoBoss at all. What's the data type for the return value of the `boss_db:find/2` function? Assuming `Users` is a list of records, I guess you could do something like:

```
Users0 = boss_db:find(consumer, []),
Users = [U#user{password = ""}|| U <- Users0],
{json, [{users, Users}]}.
```